# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: [c:\XML\file.xml, c:\XML\file2.xml, c:\XML\file3.xml]

Tags: java

I get the below error when trying to update an array of xml files.

Snippet if code:

```
File dir = new File("c:\\XML");

File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml");
    }
});

DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(Arrays.toString(files));
```

ERROR:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: [c:\XML\file.xml,
>   c:\XML\file2.xml, c:\XML\file3.xml]

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your file array's indices one by one to `Document#parse()` e.g.:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(files[0]);
```

You can loop this:

```
for (File f : files) {
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(f);

    // do something with the doc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> DocumentBuilder.parse accepts as argument a File object, a String
>   containing path to file or URI.

In the above code snippet you are passing an array,
You have to modify code as follows:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(files[i])
```

And call this recursively setting the value of **i** based on the size of array **files**.

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(Arrays.toString(files));
```

You convert an array of `File`s to a *single* `String`.

```
[c:\XML\file.xml, c:\XML\file2.xml, c:\XML\file3.xml]
```

This is the representation you get.

`DocumentBuilder#parse` doesn't know how to parse several documents at once, and why should it know such a notation for a series of filenames?

You need to iterate over the files:

```
List<Document> docs = new LinkedList<Document>();
for (File aFile: files) {
    docs.add(docBuilder.parse(files[i].getName())); // Or do something different
}
```